# Heap Corruption Detected (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-corruption

I am having a problem with merge sorting. I'm using the code below, and I'm getting a heap corruption detected. It happens when I try to deallocate memory, so I would imagine I'm writing an out of bound index.

More specifically I think it's at the last for loop. When I print out the array, the first index is some garbage number, and the last index is actually the one before the last that I want. I've tried everything and I can't get around to solving this, can somebody tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong? 'Cause I can't seem to understand what the problem is.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
template <class T>
int Mergesort(T arr[], int n) {
  MergeSortRec(arr, 0, n, n);
  return 0;
}

template <class T>
void MergeSortRec(T arr[], int left, int right, int size) {
 if(right > left) {
  int mid = ((left + right) /2);

  MergeSortRec(arr, left, mid, size);
  MergeSortRec(arr, mid+1, right, size);
  Merge(arr, left, mid, right, size);
 }
 return;
}

template <class T>
void Merge(T arr[], int left, int mid, int right, int size) {
 int i = 0;
 int j = left;
 int k = mid + 1;

 T* temp = new T[right - left];

 while(j <= mid && k <= right) {
  if(arr[j] < arr[k]) {
   temp[i++] = arr[j++];
  } else {
   temp[i++] = arr[k++];
  }
 }

 while(j <= mid) {
  temp[i++] = arr[j++];
 }

 while(k <= right) {
  temp[i++] = arr[k++];
 }

 for(int a = left; a <= right; a++) {
  arr[a] = temp [a-left];
 }
```

Cheers.

Comment: Use vectors which will perform bounds checking. If you have to use arrays in your assignment, just convert the vectors back when you have done debugging.

Comment: I'll look into how to use vectors and give it a try I guess. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
T* temp = new T[right - left];

//...

for(int a = left; a <= right; a++) {
    arr[a] = temp [a-left];
}
```

You allocate `right-left` elements, but the `for` loop steps through `right-left+1` entries, so you run off the end of the array and trample on some memory you shouldn't. If you added `delete [] temp;` after that `for` loop (without it you are leaking memory!) you would probably see your error much earlier.

In fact, all your loops go one too far; it's just most obvious in this simple loop.

Comment: I've actually used an array size of 1000 even, and I keep getting the same error. The problem happens when I delete arr[], not temp[]. So I think I'm writing out of bounds on arr, but I just can't see where.

Comment: You haven't included the code that you use to call the merge sort, but perhaps that also has a similar problem of allocating one too few locations?

Comment: The code is a huge nest since it was handed to us by the prof. But what is essentially happening is that there's a function reading off a text file, and passing the size of the elements to a Mergesort function. The Mergesort function is calling this one. I will edit the original post to include that one. But I'm using 3 other sorting algorithms, and they're all working more than perfectly. It's just the merging that's not working.

Comment: "So I think I'm writing out of bounds on arr, but I just can't see where." -- Actually, nothing you're seeing should lead you to that conclusion. When you run off the end of *any* memory block, *every* memory block is at risk of corruption. You can't be sure what you landed on. It could be something some other library is using, like a buffer for I/O.

Comment: Oh, that's a new one for me. Hmm... I think I'll just rewrite the code from scratch. Cheers.

Comment: The point is that these things tend to happen on the first `delete` after the heap's been corrupted. It doesn't matter what's being deleted; the free block list is usually just that--a list--and trashing one set of next/previous pointers (which OSes usually store just outside of the blocks they return via `malloc` or `new`) breaks most of, if not the whole free block list.

Comment: Rewrite from scratch? What will you do different to prevent a repeat of this bug? Just go through the places where you access arrays and make sure you know what the whole range of indices is, and make sure the arrays are allocated to that size.

Comment: I see. I'm still new to C++ and any details on how it works are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking of just testing the new code step by step. Honestly what I did is that after I returned to the MergeSortRecur function I printed out all of the indices (cout << i) and it didn't go above 100 (which is the size of the elements). I've looked up everywhere to see how to better write this function, but most of the examples are almost identical to the one I'm using.

Comment: Short version: `bar = new Foo[N]` allocates an array of `N` consecutive items of type `Foo`, and stores the pointer to the first item in `bar`. These items can be accessed via `bar[0]` through `bar[N - 1]`.

Comment: I see. And I'm writing at bar[k] where k reaches a 100, so I'm writing on the 101th index. Yupe, I think I got it. Cheers.